# using Scanner and next() with println error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;

class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    RunnableDemo( String name){
        threadName = name;
    }
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("asd");
    }

    public void start ()
    {
        if (t == null)
        {
            t = new Thread (this, threadName);
            t.start ();
        }
    }

}

class RunnableDemo1 implements Runnable {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;

    RunnableDemo1( String name){
        threadName = name;
    }
    public void run() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter here:");
        String x = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(x);
    }

    public void start ()
    {
        if (t == null)
        {
            t = new Thread (this, threadName);
            t.start ();
        }
    }

}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        RunnableDemo1 R1 = new RunnableDemo1( "Thread-1");
        R1.start();
        sleep(1000);
        RunnableDemo R2 = new RunnableDemo( "Thread-2");
        R2.start();


    }
}
```

Println will print a line to the command prompt but in.nexLine() (also tried in.next() does not recognize it. Is there any way I am able to print a string to the command prompt and have the scanner recognize it? Or something similar?

Comment: Please consider posting a valid [mcve] or as close to one as you can get. Also you know that `reciveMessage != receiveMessage`, right? Spelling matters.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry, was just a mistype on this page.  All I'm asking is how to get in.next() (or something similiar) to be recognized by println() (or something similar).  Since println just prints the text and a new line character and for some reason next() does not recognize that

Comment: [mcve] please for the best chance of getting quick and correct help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't understand what I am missing, I gave minimal and complete code with what exactly is going wrong(a verifiable example).  I edited it to make it more clear

Comment: You gave minimal code that **does not compile or run for us**, so no it is not "complete". What use is that?

Comment: Please read the [mcve] link, it's all explained. Also look at the [sscce](http://sscce.org) link to see more on what we need.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This project is enormous, using many different packages, It would be very difficult to upload all of it.  But I know the error is with the way println() and Scanner.next() interact, I'm just not sure how to fix it

Comment: We're not asking you to upload all of it. If you'd just read the links as has been requested multiple times, you'd understand exactly what I'm requesting. Please do so (again).

Comment: Your question has **nothing whatsoever to do with** [tag:rmi].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.println` shouldn't send anything to the server since it sends the String to the standard out only, usually the console, unless you've re-routed the standard out, something that I don't recommend that you do. Instead you need to actually send something to the server, perhaps in your notifyObservers method, but hard to say without your [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

In all this remains a very incomplete question until you improve it.

Edit: yes the [Observable API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) shows that `public void notifyObservers(Object arg)` has an overload that accepts an Object parameter. Why not pass your String in there?

---

Edit 2: OK, you're confused, because that's not how you have one class communicate with another. Printing something out to the console will not trigger the System.in to update in another thread. Again, do what I stated above.

Comment: I heavily modified the post so you are able to easily compile and see what I am trying to accomplish.  I removed all RMI aspects and instead use multi thread so it can easily be compiled.  But from what I can understand form your post, println isn't able to interact with scanner?

Comment: Okay thanks, I will look at passing an object parameter